# Pros/cons using cursor approach vs. begin-end-exception approach for single-row queries in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Whenever a query in PL/SQL is written where only one row is expected, there are two ways it is often done:

1. Use an implicit `SELECT INTO`, and check for `TOO_MANY_ROWS` and `NO_DATA_FOUND` exceptions.
2. Use an explicit cursor and just fetch the first row from the cursor.

Though both the approaches yield the same result, what are the pros and cons of these approaches?

Comment: @Jeffery Kemp - Thanks for editing the question. It looks good now and focuses the main intention of the question. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a select statement is expected to return exactly one row then a "SELECT INTO" is the better approach.  Yes, many developers prefer to use a cursor and fetch only one row because it saves them the "bother" of dealing with NO_DATA_FOUND - i.e. they sweep the problem under the carpet and leave the user with a mysterious bug.  I [blogged about this bad practice* recently](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.com/2011/04/curse-of-cursor.html).

(* a bad practice that is often sadly enshrined in project PL/SQL standards!)

As for counting and then querying, that just doubles the work so is to be avoided too.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the link to your blog!  You should blog more ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your blog link. Good example of the worst case scenarios using cursors for single row thrown queries. At least now I got a point to support myself before my colleagues :-)

Comment: Also, the SELECT INTO method is faster.  Look at page 85 of this presentation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/plsql-performance-debunking-the-myt-131194.zip